# Query All Attachments and Order by Parent Publish Date

Tags: wp-query, attachments, order

I'm working on a project where I need to query all of the image attachments and then organize them based on the date the post they were attached to was published.

The query below worked well, except that the order from `$post_image_query` was not being maintained in the output from `$the_query`.

So my question was how can I query all attachments and order them by the publishing date of their parents?

```
// Get All Post IDs
$post_image_query = new WP_Query( 
    array( 
        'post_type' => 'post', 
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'fields' => 'ids'
    ) 
);

// Get All Attachments of Posts from $post_image_query 
$the_query = new WP_Query( 
    array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_status' => 'inherit',
        'post_parent__in' => $post_image_query->posts
    );
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time reading the documentation for [WP_Query's Order & Orderby Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) I found the following listed parameter to almost get me there:

> 'post__in' - Preserve post ID order given in the post__in array
>   (available since Version 3.5).

Unfortunately I wasn't using `post__in` but rather `post_parent__in` so ordering by `post__in` didn't work.

It wasn't listed in the documentation, but I decided to try and order by `post_parent__in` and was happy to find out that it worked!

The final result:

```
// Get All Post IDs
$post_image_query = new WP_Query( 
    array( 
        'post_type' => 'post', 
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'fields' => 'ids'
    ) 
);

// Get All Attachments of Posts from $post_image_query 
$the_query = new WP_Query( 
    array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_status' => 'inherit',
        'orderby' => 'post_parent__in',
        'post_parent__in' => $post_image_query->posts
    );
);
```

This may have been a natural troubleshooting thought to other people, but I was getting close to asking a question here about it because I had no idea how to make it happen :)